# Word mincing/mixing program

Tags: c, merge

This is what my output currently looks like (which is not how I want it) and what the correct output should look like -

[image: This is what my output currently looks like (which is not how I want it) and what the correct output should look like,]I want my program that I am currently making take the inputs from 2 .txt files and then put them into 1 output .txt file but the output has to look something like this

For example, if the two input files contents were:
“Now is the time.”
“For the quick brown fox.”
Then my output line would be:
“Now foR Is thE quick Time browN fox.”

The program should also capitalize the first letter of each word from the first file and the last letter of each word from the
second file until I exhaust one line then transfers all remaining words from the longer line to my
output file unchanged. At the end of each set of lines end with a period and write a line to the
output file like seen above

My current code in c is as follows:

```
/* 
*   Copyright (C) 2018 Canton Robinson
*
*   This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
*   it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
*   the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
*   (at your option) any later version.
*
*   This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
*   but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
*   MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
*   GNU General Public License for more details.
*
*   You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
*   along with this program.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
*/
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) 
{ 
 FILE *fp1 , *fp2, *fp3;
 int ch;

  if (argc !=4) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: mincer File1 File2 destFile\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

 if ((fp1 = fopen(argv[1], "rb")) ==NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Can't open %s\n", argv[1]);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

         if ((fp2 = fopen(argv[2], "rb")) ==NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Can't open %s\n", argv[2]);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

  if ((fp3 = fopen(argv[3], "wb")) ==NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Can't open %s\n", argv[3]);
            fclose(fp1);
            fclose(fp2);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

   // Copy contents of first file to file3.txt 
   while ((ch = fgetc(fp1)) != EOF) 
      fputc(ch, fp3); 

   // Copy contents of second file to file3.txt 
   while ((ch = fgetc(fp2)) != EOF) 
      fputc(ch, fp3); 

   printf("Merged %s and %s into %s", argv[1], argv[2], argv[3]); 

   fclose(fp1); 
   fclose(fp2); 
   fclose(fp3); 
   return 0; 
}
```

Comment: What problems do you face, or: what's your actual question?

Comment: my main problems on my program are that it doesnt do specifically this "For example, if the two input files contents were: “Now is the time.” “For the quick brown fox.” Then my output line would be: “Now foR Is thE The quick Time browN fox.”" I just have no idea on how I can make my program do this, I got the program to compile and to merge 2 files but it doesnt have the proper output, it does line for line to the output file rather then word for word, I can add photos if needed

Comment: you need to jumble words and make some letters Capital ?

Comment: can you share the first file & second file ? i mean screenshot ?

Comment: no, it needs to take the inputs of 2 .txt files and then puts them into a output file but say the words "Now is the time" was in one .txt file and "For the quick brown fox" was in another text file, what I need the output file to have in it is I need the program to capitalize the first letter of each word from the first file and the last letter of each word from the second file until I use up one line from 1 file then transfers all remaining words from the longer line in the remaining file to my output file unchanged.

Comment: Here is a website containing a lot of useful information on [how to debug code](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: I just added a screenshot of what my output currently has in it and what the correct output should look like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This loop may do what you want. Sorry, can't test the code.

```
while(isspace(ch1=fgetc(fp1)));
while(isspace(ch2=fgetc(fp2)));

while(ch1!=EOF || ch2!=EOF) {
    if(ch1!=EOF) {
        fputc(toupper(ch1), fp3);
        while((ch1=fgetc(fp1))!=EOF && !isspace(ch1))
            fputc(ch1, fp3);
        fputc(' ', fp3);
        while(isspace(ch1))
            ch1=fgetc(fp1);
    }
    if(ch2!=EOF) {
        for(lch2=ch2; (ch2=fgetc(fp2))!=EOF && !isspace(ch2); lch2=ch2)
            fputc(lch2, fp3);
        fputc(toupper(lch2), fp3);
        fputc(' ', fp3);
        while(isspace(ch2))
            ch2=fgetc(fp2);
    }
}
```

Comment: this loop almost does what I want it to do completely thank you, the only things that need to be fixed in my program are the capitalization of words at the end of the output file and implementing something that will allow for periods "." to be always put into the output file