# Word Mincing program

Tags: c

This is the program requirements as of current below:

Please write a C program which accepts a command line from the user via the console,
consisting of three file names, two input files and one output file. All three are text files. You can
use the file extension .txt.
Your program should open the first two files for input and the third file for output. Diagnose and
thoroughly test code provisions for informatively diagnosing any failed file opening.
Then, your program should read one line each from each file until reaching and end of file. For
each line, transfer one word from each line, merging them together to form an output line.
Capitalize the first letter of each word from the first file and the last letter of each word from the
second file until you exhaust one line. Transfer all remaining words from the longer line to your
output line unchanged. At the end of each set of lines end with a period and write a line to the
output file. If one file ends before the other simply transfer the remaining lines to your output file
unchanged. Print counts showing what your program processed.
For example, if two lines were:
“Now is the time.”
“For the quick brown fox.”
Then your output line would be:
“Now foR Is thE The quicK Time browN fox.”

This is the program requirements that I need help with

thank you to anyone who can/has helped so far

```
/* 
*   Copyright (C) 2018 Canton Robinson
*
*   This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
*   it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
*   the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
*   (at your option) any later version.
*
*   This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
*   but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
*   MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
*   GNU General Public License for more details.
*
*   You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
*   along with this program.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
*/
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <ctype.h>
int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) 
{ 
 FILE *fp1 , *fp2, *fp3;
 int ch1, ch2, lch2;
 //int s;
 //int count1=0 , count2=0;

  if (argc !=4) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: mincers File1 File2 destFile\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

 if ((fp1 = fopen(argv[1], "rb")) ==NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Can't open %s\n", argv[1]);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

         if ((fp2 = fopen(argv[2], "rb")) ==NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Can't open %s\n", argv[2]);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

  if ((fp3 = fopen(argv[3], "wb")) ==NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Can't open %s\n", argv[3]);
            fclose(fp1);
            fclose(fp2);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

   // Copy contents of first file to file3.txt 
   //while ((ch = fgetc(fp1)) != EOF) 
    //  fputc(ch, fp3); 

   // Copy contents of second file to file3.txt 
  // while ((ch = fgetc(fp2)) != EOF) 
     // fputc(ch, fp3);
    //       while((s = fgetc(fp1)) != EOF) {
     //   if(s == ' ')  count1++;
   // }
   // while((s = fgetc(fp2)) != EOF) {
    //    if(s == ' ') count2++;
   // }

    while(isspace(ch1=fgetc(fp1)));
    while(isspace(ch2=fgetc(fp2)));

    while(ch1!=EOF || ch2!=EOF) {
    if(ch1!=EOF) {
        fputc(toupper(ch1), fp3);
        while((ch1=fgetc(fp1))!=EOF && !isspace(ch1))
            fputc(ch1, fp3);
        fputc(' ', fp3);
        while(isspace(ch1))
            ch1=fgetc(fp1);
    }
    if(ch2!=EOF) {
        //fputc(tolower(ch2), fp3);
        for(lch2=ch2; (ch2=fgetc(fp2))!=EOF && !isspace(ch2); lch2=ch2)
            fputc(lch2, fp3);
        fputc(tolower(lch2), fp3);
        fputc(' ', fp3);
        while(isspace(ch2))
            ch2=fgetc(fp2);
    }
} 

   printf("Merged %s and %s into %s", argv[1], argv[2], argv[3]); 

   fclose(fp1); 
   fclose(fp2); 
   fclose(fp3); 

  // printf("%d , %d\n", count1, count2);
   return 0; 
}
```

Comment: First, there's no need to include an image of your entire screen when you could just include the **text** that the program needs to output. Second, *please* don't ask us to infer requirements from your screenshot... explain what the program is supposed to do, how it's currently failing to perform correctly, and where you're having trouble. How are you supposed to decide which characters to capitalize? Why is the first example more correct than the second? What's in the input files?

Comment: The top of the screenshot is what my output from my text files are containing which is the words "Now is the time" in one text file and "For the quick brown fox" in the other text file, what I need my program to output is the bottom line of the screenshot

Comment: If that output is the only requirement then your program just needs to call `printf("Now foR Is thE The...")` or code to that effect. Obviously there's some criteria for combining the strings in the files and capitalizing certain letters. Your instructor may have even told you what those criteria are. So if you're asking how to do the assignment, it'd be helpful to say what the assignment **is**; from what's here, it's impossible to know. However, you should really try to do it yourself, because your next assignment will be harder, and you won't be able to do it if you can't do this one.

Comment: I am not asking for my program to be done for me, I've never done anything like this before in coding and I could use some help trying to figure out capitalization, Is the method I am using right now good? Or is their an alternative easier way? Also, It can be any three files the user needs, two input files, and one output file

Comment: Is this question any different than your previous https://stackoverflow.com/q/53314327 (which got answered)?

Comment: What is the difference between the output you achieve and the output you want? If you can describe that, you are one step closer to solving your problem. Otherwise it makes helping you easier.

Comment: yes, it is, I have the capitalization somewhat correctly, right now my output is:

Comment: Output is: Now FoR Is thE The quicK Time browN foX

Comment: You probably need to improve your output for failed file opening to match your requirements. Currently the output only differs potentially in the file name, more helpful for debugging would be "Cannot open %s as first file.\n"``.

Comment: Actually providing the output is a good idea, but better do that in the question, instead of hiding that info in a comment. Also, please try to describe the difference between the desired and the achieved output. That really is the path to success. Try it.

Answer (score 0):

You've got an awful lot going on in one giant `main()` function. The instructions are pretty complicated: there are a number of things you need to do, each of which requires several steps. Doesn't trying to keep all the steps and sub-steps in your head at the same time make your head spin? There must be a better way, right?

The better way is: **Break it down.** That is, go through the instructions and make a list of the different tasks you need to accomplish to be able to process the files. For example, you need to be able to:

- read a line from a file
- find the next word on a line
- capitalize the first letter of a word
- capitalize the last letter of a word
- merge two lines

...and so on. Wouldn't it be a whole lot easier to think about this problem if you didn't try to think about it all at once? It'd be nice if all the details were taken care of and you could just write a very high-level program that looks like this:

```
while there are lines in both file1 and file2, do {
    read a line from file1 into line1
    read a line from file2 into line2
    merge line1 and line2 and save the result in line_out
    write line_out into file3
}
copy any remaining lines from file1 into file3
copy any remaining lines from file2 into file3
```

That seems pretty straightforward, doesn't it? It's clear that it does the fundamental behavior that's asked for: reading one line from each of two files, merging them, and writing them to the output. What you need to do is to write that program. Forget about the capitalization or mixing the words from the two lines together or any of that, **but:** when you write the program above, **each of those steps should be a function call**. So you'll write a function like:

```
void readOneLine(FILE inputFile, char *line, int maxChars)
```

that reads a line from `inputFile` into `line`, making sure not to read more than `maxChars`. You can similarly create a `writeOneLine(FILE outputFile char *line)` function that writes a line into a file, and between those two functions you've already got most of what you need to write the program above.

Merging the lines in the way the requirements describe seems kinda complicated, so don't worry about that at first. Just write a placeholder function that takes two lines and gives you back a third line:

```
void mergeLines(char *line1, char *line2, char *line_out)
```

Don't worry about the requirements right away. You could just concatenate the two lines to start, or even just set `line_out` to some constant string and ignore the two input lines at first. Once you *have* the `mergeLines()` function, you've got something you can use to write the program, and you can worry about merging the two input lines the right way later.

So, now you've got the tools you need to write the program outlined above. Do it. Your `main()` function will be very short -- just a bit of code to open the files and create some buffers for the lines you're going to read and write, and then about eight lines of code to do the actual work.

Once you've got that working, you can get to improving it. The main problem is that `mergeLines()` doesn't do the right thing at all, because we basically ignored it. And it's still pretty daunting -- how do you merge two lines and make sure the right words are capitalized in the right places? How do you even capitalize some words at the beginning and others at the end? Once again, you're going to **break it down** into smaller steps, and write a function for each one of those steps. So you might write a function to get the next word in a line, for example. And you might write one function that capitalizes the first letter of a word, and another one that capitalizes the last letter of a word. Or you might just write one function that capitalizes any letter you tell it to. There are no wrong answers here — it's just a matter of how you want to do it. The main thing is that whenever something seems even a little complicated, you break it down into smaller steps that are easier to manage, and then write the larger process in terms of those steps.